# Can I add an eventlistener to an img that I append to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, appendchild

This is my first ever question here, so apologies if i'm not asking correctly.
I want to add an eventlistener to an img that I later on want to append to a div.
Somehow my event isn't firing.. Anyone has any idea? If I add the event to the div i'm appending the img to, it fires, but not when I add the event to the img.

The goal is to have an img of a product on a webshop change when I click on it.

See code below:

```
for (let product of selectedProducts) {
    let prdct = document.createElement('div');
    let productimg = document.createElement('img');
    productimg.addEventListener('click', ChangePicture);
    productimg.className = "productimg";
    productimg.src = "../img/test.png";
    

    prdct.appendChild(productimg);
    let contentprdct = `${product.Model}<br />${product.Category}<br /><b>€ ${product.Price.toFixed(2)}</b>`;

    prdct.innerHTML += contentprdct;

    

    categorycontainer.appendChild(prdct);
    article.appendChild(categorycontainer);
}

function ChangePicture() {
if(this.src == "../img/test.png") {
    this.src = "../img/test2.png";
}
else if(this.src == "../img.test2.png") {
    this.src = "../img/test.png";
}
```

}

Comment: The issue is that you are using `.innerHTML += <something>`.  What that effectively does is `prdct.innerHTML = prdct.innerHTML + <something>`.  The forced translation of the Element in the prdct to a string, makes it lose any event bindings you put on it.  To keep your event bindings you need to create the other things as actual Elements and `appendChild` them to the `prdct` as well

Comment: With regards to how to do that, without having to put a tag around the whole `contentprdct` content, take a look at `document.createDocumentFragment()` or `new DocumentFragment()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Comment: @Taplar You're my hero!

As this code is used for a exercise for my course, I'm putting the img inside a new div. My project is full of divs, but at least I understand the code. I read the documentation for the DocumentFragment but didn't understand all of it.

I prefer using code that I understand and can explain. That's why i stick to divs for this one.

Thanks alot for taking the time to answer my question.